# Get access-list via SNMP

Tags: cisco, snmp, access-control-list

Is it possible to get the access-list of a Cisco Router via SNMP?
I have been searching for that but until now i have not found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching through Cisco's SNMP Object Navigator it doesn't appear possible to get more than the name of ACLs used for QoS only. Maybe I just missed it though.

http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do

Comment: You are right. After some searching i also came to that conclusion, it is only possible to get the name of ACLs used for QoS only.